# How can I have a collection of objects that differ by their associated type?

Tags: collections, types, rust

I have a program that involves examining a complex data structure to see if it has any defects. (It's quite complicated, so I'm posting example code.) All of the checks are unrelated to each other, and will all have their own modules and tests.

More importantly, each check has its own error type that contains different information about how the check failed for each number. I'm doing it this way instead of just returning an error string so I can test the errors (it's why `Error` relies on `PartialEq`).

### My Code So Far

I have traits for `Check` and `Error`:

```
trait Check {
    type Error;
    fn check_number(&self, number: i32) -> Option<Self::Error>;
}

trait Error: std::fmt::Debug + PartialEq {
    fn description(&self) -> String;
}
```

And two example checks, with their error structs. In this example, I want to show errors if a number is negative or even:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct EvenError {
    number: i32,
}
struct EvenCheck;

impl Check for EvenCheck {
    type Error = EvenError;

    fn check_number(&self, number: i32) -> Option<EvenError> {
        if number < 0 {
            Some(EvenError { number: number })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl Error for EvenError {
    fn description(&self) -> String {
        format!("{} is even", self.number)
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct NegativeError {
    number: i32,
}
struct NegativeCheck;

impl Check for NegativeCheck {
    type Error = NegativeError;

    fn check_number(&self, number: i32) -> Option<NegativeError> {
        if number < 0 {
            Some(NegativeError { number: number })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl Error for NegativeError {
    fn description(&self) -> String {
        format!("{} is negative", self.number)
    }
}
```

I know that in this example, the two structs look identical, but in my code, there are many different structs, so I can't merge them. Lastly, an example `main` function, to illustrate the kind of thing I want to do:

```
fn main() {
    let numbers = vec![1, -4, 64, -25];
    let checks = vec![
        Box::new(EvenCheck) as Box<Check<Error = Error>>,
        Box::new(NegativeCheck) as Box<Check<Error = Error>>,
    ]; // What should I put for this Vec's type?

    for number in numbers {
        for check in checks {
            if let Some(error) = check.check_number(number) {
                println!("{:?} - {}", error, error.description())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the code in [the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=1804e0f83d0183de071b05cf040d7a2a).

### Solutions I've Tried

The closest thing I've come to a solution is to remove the associated types and have the checks return `Option<Box<Error>>`. However, I get this error instead:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Error` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:4:55
  |
4 |     fn check_number(&self, number: i32) -> Option<Box<Error>>;
  |                                                       ^^^^^ the trait `Error` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: the trait cannot use `Self` as a type parameter in the supertraits or where-clauses
```

because of the `PartialEq` in the `Error` trait. Rust has been great to me thus far, and I really hope I'm able to bend the type system into supporting something like this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found a way to do it that I'm happy with. Instead of having a vector of `Box<Check<???>>` objects, have a vector of closures that all have the same type, abstracting away the very functions that get called:

```
fn main() {
    type Probe = Box<Fn(i32) -> Option<Box<Error>>>;

    let numbers: Vec<i32> = vec![ 1, -4, 64, -25 ];
    let checks = vec![
        Box::new(|num| EvenCheck.check_number(num).map(|u| Box::new(u) as Box<Error>)) as Probe,
        Box::new(|num| NegativeCheck.check_number(num).map(|u| Box::new(u) as Box<Error>)) as Probe,
    ];

    for number in numbers {
        for check in checks.iter() {
            if let Some(error) = check(number) {
                println!("{}", error.description());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not only does this allow for a vector of `Box<Error>` objects to be returned, it allows the `Check` objects to provide their own Error associated type which doesn't need to implement `PartialEq`. The multiple `as`es look a little messy, but on the whole it's not *that* bad.

Answer (score 8):

When you write an `impl Check` and specialize your `type Error` with a concrete type, you are ending up with different types.

In other words, `Check<Error = NegativeError>` and `Check<Error = EvenError>` are statically different types. Although you might expect `Check<Error>` to describe both, note that in Rust `NegativeError` and `EvenError` are not *sub-types* of `Error`. They are guaranteed to implement all methods defined by the `Error` trait, but then calls to those methods will be statically dispatched to physically different functions that the compiler creates (each will have a version for `NegativeError`, one for `EvenError`).

Therefore, you can't put them in the same `Vec`, even boxed (as you discovered). It's not so much a matter of knowing how much space to allocate, it's that `Vec` requires its types to be homogeneous (you can't have a `vec![1u8, 'a']` either, although a `char` is representable as a `u8` in memory).

Rust's way to "erase" some of the type information and gain the dynamic dispatch part of subtyping is, as you discovered, trait objects.

If you want to give another try to the trait object approach, you might find it more appealing with a few tweaks...

1. You might find it much easier if you used the `Error` trait in [`std::error`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/index.html) instead of your own version of it.

   You may need to `impl Display` to create a description with a dynamically built `String`, like so:

   ```
   impl fmt::Display for EvenError {
       fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
           write!(f, "{} is even", self.number)
       }
   }

   impl Error for EvenError {
       fn description(&self) -> &str { "even error" }
   }
   ```
2. Now you can drop the associated type and have `Check` return a trait object:

   ```
   trait Check  {
       fn check_number(&self, number: i32) -> Option<Box<Error>>;
   }
   ```

   your `Vec` now has an expressible type:

   ```
   let mut checks: Vec<Box<Check>> = vec![
       Box::new(EvenCheck) ,
       Box::new(NegativeCheck) ,
   ];
   ```
3. The best part of using `std::error::Error`...

   is that now you don't need to use `PartialEq` to understand what error was thrown. `Error` has various types of downcasts and type checks if you do need to retrieve the concrete `Error` type out of your trait object.

   ```
   for number in numbers {
       for check in &mut checks {
           if let Some(error) = check.check_number(number) {
               println!("{}", error);

               if let Some(s_err)= error.downcast_ref::<EvenError>() {
                   println!("custom logic for EvenErr: {} - {}", s_err.number, s_err)                    
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

[full example on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=92c48becd46daf6af647&version=stable)

Comment: I ended up coming back to this problem three years later, and your answer proved extremely useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you some refactoring.

First, I'm pretty sure, that vectors should be homogeneous in Rust, so there is no way to supply elements of different types for them. Also you cannot downcast traits to reduce them to a common base trait (as I remember, there was a question about it on SO).

So I'd use algebraic type with explicit match for this task, like this:

```
enum Checker {
    Even(EvenCheck),
    Negative(NegativeCheck),
}

let checks = vec![
    Checker::Even(EvenCheck),
    Checker::Negative(NegativeCheck),
];
```

As for error handling, consider use [FromError](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.FromError.html) framework, so you will able to involve [try!](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html) macro in your code and to convert error types from one to another.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. You're correct that vectors are homogenous in Rust, but it's possible to convert the elements to the same type (such as a Box trait object) to make them all fit.

I considered creating a new `enum` with every possible checker in it, but I plan to have dozens of these checkers with many lines of code each, and the code would quickly get repetitive and unwieldy. Basically, I'd like a way to use trait objects in order to write all this code for me!

Comment: I don't believe, that there is a way to convert all the elements to the same type in your case. Just imagine if you are a compiler, then how much stack space would you allocate for `check.check_number(number)` result in the loop? It definitely shoud be something of constant size, so we came again to either union type (enum), either pointer, like your `Option<Box<Check>>` version. So maybe you should consider to get rid of `PartialEq` impl to make it work.