# Returning a trait with an associated type

Tags: generics, struct, rust, traits, associated-types

```
struct A;
struct PropA;

struct B;
struct PropB;

trait AB{
    type prop;
    fn a(&self) -> ();
    fn b(&self, p: Self::prop) -> ();
}

impl AB for A{
    type prop = PropA;
    fn a(&self)->(){}
    fn b(&self, p: Self::prop) -> (){}
}
impl AB for B{
    type prop = PropB;
    fn a(&self)->(){}
    fn b(&self, p: Self::prop) -> (){}
}

fn get_a_or_b(s: &str) -> Option<Box<dyn AB<prop=_>>>{
    match s{
        "a" => Some(Box::new(A)),
        "b" => Some(Box::new(B)),
        _=> None
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8bc7292a013a11bca64104ae54180f67)

I am returning two different structs `A`&`B` based on a string input.

I get `the type placeholder '_' is not allowed within types on item signatures` when specifying associated type as placeholder.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there's a misconception here; `dyn AB<Prop = A>` and `dyn AB<Prop = B>` are different types, the first is a dynamic `AB<Prop = A>` and the second is a dynamic `AB<Prop = B>`. What this means is that you cannot leave generic types and associated types up to the dynamic aspect.

This is different than when the associated type is not mentioned:

```
fn foo<T: AB>() {
    let my_fn: fn(&T, T::Prop) = T::b;
}
```

Where we access the `T::Prop` instead of assigning it.

---

All types must be concrete, and `dyn AB<Prop = A>` on one branch, and `dyn AB<Prop = B>` on another branch is not concrete, but could be should you package it up under an enum:

```
enum AOrB {
    A(Box<dyn AB<Prop = A>>),
    B(Box<dyn AB<Prop = B>>),
}
```

Comment: But then if i need to call `a_or_b.a()` i need to write repetitive match arms, which i guess i can use a macro ?